# Wanting to use a particle beam in an alignment tool. Will any commonly available radioisotopes give me a strong count if I made my slit very narrow?

Tags: radioactivity, particle-detectors

As I move my detector from left to right across the slit, I need to be able to pick up a very narrow Gaussian particle count distribution from a couple inches away. I need to be able to resolve the curve and tell where I am on it at increments of 0.03" or less, so I may need to make my collimator slit very narrow, perhaps 0.01" wide. Are there any commonly available radioisotopes that could give me strong beta particle counts of at least tens per second at that distance? Or are they all too weak?

Edit- Follow up question: What sensor should I use if I plan to hook it up to a microcontroller?

Comment: Sounds a bit dangerous. Make sure you're taking all the necessary precautions. Have you thought about using laser light, perhaps delivered by a single mode optical fiber? Better still, can you draw your setup and we can have a look at it to see whether there might be something safer you can do?

Comment: Commonly available radioisotopes are by definition not dangerous. I'm trying to get away from using lasers because of certain operational constraints. Specifically, I don't want the operator to have to align any beams.

Comment: You'll still need to align the source - slit line with your aligned apparatus. If you used a class I pigtailed laser system with a miniaturized collimator on it, there'd be no alignment of the delivery system needed and you'd need only to align the collimator case in the same way as you align the source - slit line. It would be the same problem in both cases. I'm guessing you'd be locating the source at a calibration point / state, and measuring displacements from there? If so, then you wouldn't need any light alignment at all.

Comment: So what I'm really trying to get away with here is only needing to align two planes, and not having to aim any beams at targets. The system will be difficult to access after the first setup. I'm also averse to lasers, because sometimes the rules around here require the user to be certified to use "hazardous energy" :/ So that's why I started thinking about particles. But today a coworker turned me on to the idea of collimated LED light, so I might lean that direction. I need to investigate the laser idea more though. Are the lasers you mentioned fan lasers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Commercially available" radioactive sources... It really depends on whether you have a license (which depends on the country). Assuming you are in the US and have no NRC license, then you can legally have a sealed 10 µCi source (these exist in many fire alarms, for example). That will give you 37,000 decays per second, emitted into random directions. The question becomes - what solid angle of this radiation can you use?

Am-241 has an emission at about 59.5 keV, which is amenable to collimation with a few mm of tungsten. If you can afford slit collimation (only need to align in one direction at a time) and you want to be able to resolve 0.03" increments from 2" distance (or about 1° angular resolution) then you probably need a slit with that aspect ratio (that is, you first need to collimate the source down to a certain size, then have a slit to limit the beam) - because a "point source" of radiation is rarely a true point.

This diagram gives the idea:

[image]

Now the efficiency with which you are getting radiation to a detector (with a width S) depends on the other dimensions in this diagram. It will depend critically on the size of your source - if it's too big you need to have the first collimator present, and that will really hurt. Otherwise, the width and distance of the second slit will determine the solid angle - and thus the number of events that reach your detector.

A linear slit with 1° opening, and that extends ± 20° in the perpendicular direction, will have a geometric efficiency that is roughly given by the area of such a slit projected onto a sphere divided by the area of the sphere:

$$G = \frac{1\cdot \frac{\pi}{180} \times 20\cdot\frac{\pi}{180}}{4\pi} \approx 0.05\%$$

For your 10 µCi source, if it's small enough, that means 18 counts per second. If your source is bigger than the resolution you want to achieve, you will have to use the second slit - with a further reduction in counts.

In medicine, there's a modality called SPECT imaging (single photon emission computed tomography); it's also known as nuclear medicine (because it's used to image molecules labeled with radioactive isotopes, injected into a patient). The problem of collimation (of the detector) in order to image the origin of the radiation is one of the big problems for this modality. Either you get lots of counts but don't know (very well) where they came from, or you have just a few, with good precision. The above calculation illustrates that in a nutshell...

As for your follow-up question: there are various detectors available for this type of radiation. Since you will be subject to background, you will want it well shielded, and perhaps capable of energy discrimination (so you only detect radiation of the right energy and reject everything else). For compactness, CdZnTe detectors might be hard to beat, although modern scintillator+silicon photomultiplier devices are becoming more attractive.

Are you sure that using radioactive sources is the way to go? I wonder if we're [solving an XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/212464)...

Comment: You might clarify that the 60 keV line you're describing here is an incidental photon. The primary health risk form an Amerecium source would be internal exposure to the alpha lines. With an encapsulated source you can have the (slightly blurred) photons without direct exposure to the alphas. Which is a good thing.

Comment: @dmckee you are right. But honestly - in a case like this, "if you have to ask you probably ought not do it". I didn't make that point explicitly; thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Floris - I totally know what you mean about the X Y problem. In this case, what I'm really trying to get away with here is only needing to align two planes, and not having to aim any beams at targets.  I'm also averse to lasers, because sometimes the rules around here require the user to be certified to use "hazardous energy" :/ So that's why I started thinking about particles. The isotope I had in mind was a 10 µCi Cesium sample embedded in a puck. And the figure I came to for detections/s was the same as yours (but for slightly different reasons)!

Comment: You could easily use a non-laser light source (LED with collimation) - unless you worry about contamination (dirt, smoke) affecting the optical system badly, it is a MUCH better idea than using a radioactive source. Especially since Cs-137 has a rather high energy emission which is hard to collimate (and detect).

Comment: Yeah, a coworker turned me on to the collimated LED idea today. I wasn't sold until he said I could buy them off the shelf and use a passive retroreflector to bounce the light back to a linear photodetector. I'm starting to look around for them now. Honestly, I know the decay particle idea sounds crazy at first, but I do still think it would be feasible and safe. 18 counts per second is a bit low, but I bet I could make it work. The only major drawback is that people don't understand dosimetry.

Comment: There's also the cost and complexity of the detector, and the speed of response. A quadrant photodiode (perhaps with a phase locked modulation to give very high ambient noise rejection) is a really solid method of doing this. If the distance is well defined you can use a pinhole aperture focused on the diode, and you will see small X and Y shifts... with the ability to align to micron precision. That may be more than you need - but it could be done, and easily. But honestly - a 1 mW laser is safe and effective. Put an ND filter in front of it... get whatever intensity you are comfortable with